# How to use node in wsl - zsh: exec format error: node

Tags: node.js, homebrew, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I am using windows 10 linux subsystem - linux 20.04. I have installed brew and using zsh (downloaded with brew).

The problem is when i have downloaded node with brew as well it does not work and shows me the following error:

```
zsh: exec format error: node
```

And when i am typing npm:

```
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: 1: 0�: not found
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: 1: �: not found
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: 1: ����: not found
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: 1: ʌ�,�/W�%r��@�:,2�F�: not found
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: 1: ELF: not found
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: 1:R�td0�0�E0�E�K�KP�P�EP�E: not found
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: 2: K�/�q: not found
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: 1: 
                                         �
: not found                               �0�0�E0�E�O�
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: 10: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Thanks for any kind of help :)

Comment: I removed node-modules and re-installed the packages, and fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Please see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8151) bug on the WSL github. There currently appear to be two solutions either upgrade to WSL2 or grab the package from nodesource as per [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8151#issuecomment-1236291789) comment from two days ago.

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Exec format error means that the binary for the wrong architecture is being installed - you could try using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script) to install Node - brew and WSL I can't say I've ever used but it wouldn't be my goto solution.

Comment: Thanks! I have used: curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
And the node works.

But I still jhave the same issue with npm.

Comment: Never mind. I just deleted node through brew and kept your solution and it works great. That you very much! :)

Comment: You're welcome feel free to mark this as correct if it all works fine :-)

Comment: Oh and also look at NVM it lets you run multiple versions of NodeJS and switch between them - for example on AWS you can only use nodejs 16.x for AWS Lambda - without NVM you'd need to remove your current install and install v16, WITH NVM you can just do "nvm use 16" to switch to that version.

Comment: Hey mate can you "Click the tick" if you're happy with this answer please.