# WSL issue: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to install nodejs on wsl ubunto subsytem for windows and I used the following command:
`sudo apt-get install nodejs`
When I tried to see node version using  `node --version` I got this issue:
`-bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

When I tried to see node version using  `node --version` I got this issue:
`-bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Answer (score 0):

While you have this tagged WSL2, I'm suspecting that you may actually be using WSL1 here based on the error.

This is a known issue with:

- Node
- on Ubuntu 22.04 (and others)
- on WSL1 (but not WSL2)

Check your WSL version with `wsl.exe -l -v` and edit your question to include the results.  If you really are on WSL2, then I'll delete my answer and we'll keep searching for a solution for you.

However, if as I suspect, you are using WSL1, then:

- Either upgrade to WSL2
- Or see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73616991/11810933) or [my Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1417255/1165986) (and the linked Github thread, which is extensive, IIRC) for workarounds.